# Padding between columns of a grid in javaFX

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to show a 4-column grid in a javaFX program. This is how I setup the grid.

```
 GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
 gridPane.setHgap(10); 
 gridPane.setVgap(10);
 ColumnConstraints c1 = new ColumnConstraints();
 c1.setPercentWidth(25);
 ColumnConstraints c2 = new ColumnConstraints();
 c2.setPercentWidth(25);
 ColumnConstraints c3 = new ColumnConstraints();
 c3.setPercentWidth(25);
 ColumnConstraints c4 = new ColumnConstraints();
 c4.setPercentWidth(25);
 gridPane.getColumnConstraints().addAll(c1,c2,c3,c4);
```

I have placed the label and textfields in columns 1,3 and columns 2,4 respectively. Problem is there is a gap between the textfield and the next label and hence the width of the second textfield is reduced.

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Switch on the grid lines with `gridPane.gridLinesVisibleProperty().set(true);`. Maybe you see the reason for the positioning. Also please post your complete code of your scene - is the gridPane contained in some other container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a very simple `Application using GridPane`. It uses the same `gridPane column constraints` and has `Label's` and `TextField's` as used by your example.

[image]

If you are worried about the gap between the Label and TextField, you must remember that the total width of the gridpane is divided into 4 parts (25% each). The TextField fills the space, Label fills the space too, but we see only the Text.

**MVCE Code :**

```
public class GridPaneExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setHgap(10);
        gridPane.setVgap(10);
        gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        ColumnConstraints c1 = new ColumnConstraints();
        c1.setPercentWidth(25);
        ColumnConstraints c2 = new ColumnConstraints();
        c2.setPercentWidth(25);
        ColumnConstraints c3 = new ColumnConstraints();
        c3.setPercentWidth(25);
        ColumnConstraints c4 = new ColumnConstraints();
        c4.setPercentWidth(25);
        gridPane.getColumnConstraints().addAll(c1, c2, c3, c4);

        gridPane.add(new Label("Profile ID"), 0, 0);
        gridPane.add(new TextField(), 1, 0);
        gridPane.add(new Label("Profile Name"), 2, 0);
        gridPane.add(new TextField(), 3, 0);
        gridPane.add(new Label("Transfer Object"), 0, 1);
        gridPane.add(new TextField(), 1, 1);
        gridPane.add(new Label("Class Name"), 2, 1);
        gridPane.add(new TextField(), 3, 1);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(gridPane, 500, 500));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If you are still not able to tweak your code and fix it, consider editing your code and adding a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of other properties in the [`ColumnConstraints` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/index.html?javafx/scene/layout/ColumnConstraints.html) that you can use. You probably want the labels aligned right; you probably also want the text fields to grow and fill the space, while the labels need only enough space to hold their text. So I would do something like:

```
GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
 gridPane.setHgap(10); 
 gridPane.setVgap(10);
 ColumnConstraints c1 = new ColumnConstraints();
 c1.setHalignment(HPos.RIGHT);
 c1.setHgrow(Priority.NEVER);
 ColumnConstraints c2 = new ColumnConstraints();
 c2.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
 c2.setFillWidth(true);
 ColumnConstraints c3 = new ColumnConstraints();
 c3.setHalignment(HPos.RIGHT);
 c3.setHgrow(Priority.NEVER);
 ColumnConstraints c4 = new ColumnConstraints();
 c4.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
 c4.setFillWidth(true);
 gridPane.getColumnConstraints().addAll(c1,c2,c3,c4);
```